# MariaDB Galera Cluster falls out of sync easily

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, mysql-replication, mariadb, galera

We're trying to debug an issue with a MariaDB cluster.

We're running Maria 10.0.19 on `c4.large` instances in Amazon EC2; the OS is Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty).

There are three machines clustered together, replicating fine (we can run `create database foo;` on one machine and see it on the other, etc).*But*: when we try to restore a database from a dump while all three machines are running and synced, there's an error:

```
$ du -sh *.sql
2.7G    sqldump.sql
$ cat sqldump.sql | sudo mysql
ERROR 1047 (08S01) at line 4361: WSREP has not yet prepared node for application use
```

It seems like this error has something to do with how long the import takes. If we run `service mysql stop` on two of the three nodes in the cluster and run the SQL command against the remaining node, it works fine. We can then start each of the machines in the cluster one by one to replicate the data through an SST, so it seems like this is an issue with the Galera configuration.

This doesn't only happen when running a large MySQL import: it happens during routine usage with small transactions. The large import is our most reliable way to replicate this issue, though.

The system memory usage during the import is not particularly high, nor is CPU usage. The network traffic is far below what the machine's link is capable of, and in our test there is no other traffic aside from our SSH connection.

Can someone please help understand what might be causing this issue?

Here is some more detail about the machines in the cluster and the MariaDB configuration:

Ubuntu:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

Kernel:

```
$ uname -a
Linux servername.domain 3.13.0-53-generic #89-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 20 10:34:39 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

MySQL config (IP addresses, domain, etc. in `wsrep_cluster_address` intentionally obfuscated):

```
$ find /etc/mysql/ -name "*.cnf" -exec cat {} \; | egrep -v "^#" | grep v "^$"
[mysqld]
server-id               = 965424531
bind-address            = *
max_connections         = 500
max_connect_errors      = 1000000
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2635M
log_bin                        = /var/lib/mysql/mysql/mysql-bin
expire_logs_days               = 7
sync_binlog                    = 1
binlog_format                  = MIXED
log-slave-updates              = 1
slow_query_log                 = 1
slow_query_log_file            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
[mysqld]
innodb_use_native_aio = 0
innodb_flush_method = O_DSYNC
[client]
[mysqld]
[mysqld_safe]
syslog
[mariadb]
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0
[mysqld]
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
key_buffer          = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size   = 8
myisam-recover      = BACKUP
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size    = 16M
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
expire_logs_days = 10
max_binlog_size  = 100M
[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
[mysqld]
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_debug=ON
wsrep_cluster_name="clustername"
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://10.0.X.X,10.0.X.X"
wsrep_sst_method=xtrabackup-v2
wsrep_sst_auth=sstuser:sstpassword
wsrep_node_address="10.0.1.10"
wsrep_node_name="servername.domain"
binlog_format=ROW
wsrep_on=ON
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_doublewrite=1
query_cache_size=0
innodb_log_file_size           = 256M
```

Cluster status:

```
$ sudo mysql
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 288
Server version: 10.0.19-MariaDB-1~trusty-wsrep-log mariadb.org binary distribution, wsrep_25.10.r4144

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> show status like '%wsrep%';
+------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                | Value                                             |
+------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| wsrep_local_state_uuid       | e856afdc-18af-11e5-a3a6-efccde439ba4              |
| wsrep_protocol_version       | 7                                                 |
| wsrep_last_committed         | 45764                                             |
| wsrep_replicated             | 2031                                              |
| wsrep_replicated_bytes       | 1527494811                                        |
| wsrep_repl_keys              | 9973524                                           |
| wsrep_repl_keys_bytes        | 79839767                                          |
| wsrep_repl_data_bytes        | 1447525060                                        |
| wsrep_repl_other_bytes       | 0                                                 |
| wsrep_received               | 1478                                              |
| wsrep_received_bytes         | 13040                                             |
| wsrep_local_commits          | 1750                                              |
| wsrep_local_cert_failures    | 0                                                 |
| wsrep_local_replays          | 0                                                 |
| wsrep_local_send_queue       | 0                                                 |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_max   | 2                                                 |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_min   | 0                                                 |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_avg   | 0.001140                                          |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue       | 0                                                 |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_max   | 7                                                 |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_min   | 0                                                 |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_avg   | 0.043302                                          |
| wsrep_local_cached_downto    | 45564                                             |
| wsrep_flow_control_paused_ns | 3956186469                                        |
| wsrep_flow_control_paused    | 0.005006                                          |
| wsrep_flow_control_sent      | 0                                                 |
| wsrep_flow_control_recv      | 41                                                |
| wsrep_cert_deps_distance     | 4.487445                                          |
| wsrep_apply_oooe             | 0.000000                                          |
| wsrep_apply_oool             | 0.000000                                          |
| wsrep_apply_window           | 1.000000                                          |
| wsrep_commit_oooe            | 0.000000                                          |
| wsrep_commit_oool            | 0.000000                                          |
| wsrep_commit_window          | 1.000000                                          |
| wsrep_local_state            | 4                                                 |
| wsrep_local_state_comment    | Synced                                            |
| wsrep_cert_index_size        | 11438                                             |
| wsrep_causal_reads           | 0                                                 |
| wsrep_cert_interval          | 0.000000                                          |
| wsrep_incoming_addresses     | ,,                                                |
| wsrep_evs_delayed            |                                                   |
| wsrep_evs_evict_list         |                                                   |
| wsrep_evs_repl_latency       | 0.00059098/0.000958534/0.00469729/0.000375612/732 |
| wsrep_evs_state              | OPERATIONAL                                       |
| wsrep_gcomm_uuid             | 8bcfefe4-25f7-11e5-be32-062acc002ed5              |
| wsrep_cluster_conf_id        | 88                                                |
| wsrep_cluster_size           | 3                                                 |
| wsrep_cluster_state_uuid     | e856afdc-18af-11e5-a3a6-efccde439ba4              |
| wsrep_cluster_status         | Primary                                           |
| wsrep_connected              | ON                                                |
| wsrep_local_bf_aborts        | 0                                                 |
| wsrep_local_index            | 2                                                 |
| wsrep_provider_name          | Galera                                            |
| wsrep_provider_vendor        | Codership Oy <info@codership.com>                 |
| wsrep_provider_version       | 3.9(rXXXX)                                        |
| wsrep_ready                  | ON                                                |
| wsrep_thread_count           | 2                                                 |
+------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
57 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This is usually a lost quorum, network partition, etc., event. Do you have a flaky network between the cluster nodes?

Comment: The machines are in AWS EC2 and the networking is generally extremely reliable. For example, we have xtradb multi-master setups that don't have this issue, and many other services with much higher traffic and no issues like this. The traffic on the network interfaces while running this query, as I said, is far below the capacity of the links.

Comment: Have you tried innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT?

Comment: What are your mysql logs telling about it? Galera is logging pretty well, co you should look in those files. And I can see you have configured mysql to use coflict autoincrement sequences. You should define auto_increment_increment and auto_increment_offset config values to be sure no two nodes will generate same autoincrement value.

Answer (score 1):

First, huge transactions and `LOAD DATA INFILE`on galera cluster is still a known limitation, if you have to it is advised to split these transactions by 5k-10k trx's or lesser YMMV.

Try to increase `wsrep-max-ws-size`.

Set `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0` on all nodes.

Answer (score 0):

based on https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-galera-cluster-known-limitations/

"Transaction size. While Galera does not explicitly limit the transaction size, a writeset is processed as a single memory-resident buffer and as a result, extremely large transactions (e.g. LOAD DATA) may adversely affect node performance. To avoid that, the wsrep_max_ws_rows and wsrep_max_ws_size system variables limit transaction rows to 128K and the transaction size to 1Gb by default. If necessary, users may want to increase those limits. Future versions will add support for transaction fragmentation."

Its unclear as to what your SQL actually contains however large transactions could hit these limits.

max_allowed_packet may have been larger on the machine that did the mysqldump than what you have configured.

You should post your mysql error log for such events as that will provide meaningful information.